# Fancybox Dialog Not Working on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, fancybox

Reference web site: http://www.doneupsalon.com

Fancybox 2 works fine on Safari and other modern browsers. However, when viewing on the iPad and clicking a menu link (i.e. Services) the overlay appears (screen dims) but the dialog does not appear. Did I miss a configuration setting? Thanks in advance for your help.